# How to get result from airdump-ng on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: wireless, ubuntu, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

**Issue**: when I run `airodump-ng wlp3s0mon`, no results appear.

I recently installed all kali linux tools on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from this git repo https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin

My chipset is the following and it supports monitor mode

```
root@Dimitris:~# airmon-ng
PHY    Interface    Driver          Chipset
phy0   wlp3s0      ath10k_pci   Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

- I tried killing all the conflicting processes and daemons `airmon-ng check kill | systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service`
- I use my interface in monitor mode `airmon-ng start wlp3s0`
- I've updated my system and I've updated my wireless drivers

Still `airodump-ng wlp3s0mon` fetches no data.

I literally tried everything I could think of.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bought an *Alfa AWUS036NHA* network-card and it works like magic. Apparently my internal network card wasn't compatible or something.